# How do std::exception's derivatives pass the string from their constructor to its what() virtual function?

Tags: c++, exception

I'd like to reimplement the standard exception hierarchy.

`std::exception` is defined in the following way, according to the [documentation](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception/):

```cpp
class exception {
public:
  exception () noexcept;
  exception (const exception&) noexcept;
  exception& operator= (const exception&) noexcept;
  virtual ~exception();
  virtual const char* what() const noexcept;
}
```

Now, for example, `std::logic_error` is declared like this:

```cpp
class logic_error : public exception {
public:
  explicit logic_error (const string& what_arg);
  explicit logic_error (const char* what_arg);
};
```

My question is, how does such an instantiation: `std::logic_error("Error!")` work under the hood?

The "Error!" string gets passed to `logic_error (const char* what_arg)`, and somehow passes its value to the `what()` overload in the implementation, without calling it.

One way of doing this is probably copying the string and storing it somewhere (as a private member, in the base class), then throwing it in `what()`.

I just wanted to clarify whether this is what I should do. I know that exceptions should be as lightweight as possible. I'd want to avoid storing any objects.

Is there a good way to implement this?

Comment: Your documentation is obsolete - `throw()` is no longer allowed in C++. It is now `noexcept` instead.

Comment: Better documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception, which also has a note about the implementation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error

Comment: *One way of doing this is probably copying the string and storing it somewhere (as a private member, in the base class), then throwing it in what().*
Not in the base `std::exception` class. Example implementation: the base `std::exception` class does not store any data. It's `what()` returns different strings because derived classes override this function. `std::runtime_error` is the first exception class along the hierarchy that stores a string and overrides the method, any further derived class just passes it to `std::runtime_error` constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they most likely store the string in a private member.

Not a plain `std::string` though, because copying those can throw. Probably something equivalent to `std::shared_ptr<std::string>`.